# How to get total test accuracy for pytorch lightning?

Tags: pytorch-lightning

How can the `trainer.test` method be used to get total accuracy over all batches?

I know I can implement `model.test_step` but that is for a single batch only. I need the accuracy over the whole data set. I can use `torchmetrics.Accuracy` to accumulate accuracy. But what is the proper way to combine that and get the total accuracy out? What is `model.test_step` supposed to return anyway since batchwise test scores are not very useful? I could hack it somehow, but I'm surprised that I couldn't find any example on the internet that demonstrates how to get accuracy with the pytorch-lightning native way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see here (https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/logging.html#automatic-logging) that the `on_epoch` argument in `log` automatically accumulates and logs at the end of the epoch. The right way of doing this would be:

```py
from torchmetrics import Accuracy

def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx): 
    x, y = batch 
    preds = self.forward(x) 
    loss = self.criterion(preds, y) 
    accuracy = Accuracy()
    acc = accuracy(preds, y)
    self.log('accuracy', acc, on_epoch=True)
    return loss
```

If you want a custom reduction function you can set it using the `reduce_fx` argument, the default is `torch.mean()`. `log()` can be called from any method in you `LightningModule`

Comment: How can it accumulate when it does not know the batchsize? (batches might be unequal or at the least the last one is of different size). What is the averaging method?

Also I meant testing, i.e `test_step`. Will it still work?

Comment: Updated answer based on your questions in the comment above

Comment: Thanks. I've made a test and it seems to work. Actually, the reduction method cannot be a plain `mean` because you cannot just average batch accuracy. But I suppose it rather uses the full `Accuracy` object and that object knows how it is supposed to reduce.

Comment: To understand what you are averaging over you should have a look, both at log and Accuracy() (https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classification/accuracy.html). Both of them can perform averaging in different ways.

Comment: @Gere Did you figure out how they are averaging the accuracy correctly without knowing the batch_size?

Comment: To make things even more complicated, the docs state that the `reduce_fx` is not applied if a `torchmetric` is used.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a notebook. I did some initial experimentation with the following code.

```
def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    logits = self(x)
    self.test_acc(logits, y)
    self.log('test_acc', self.test_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
```

Prints out a nicely formatted text after calling

```
model = Cifar100Model()
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=1, accelerator='cpu')
trainer.test(model, test_dataloader)
```

This printed test_acc 0.008200000040233135

I tried verifying whether the printed value is actually an average over the test data batches. By modifying the test_step as follows:

```
def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    logits = self(x)
    self.test_acc(logits, y)
    self.log('test_acc', self.test_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)

    preds = logits.argmax(dim=-1)
    acc = (y == preds).float().mean()
    print(acc)
```

Then ran trainer.test() again. This time the following values were printed out:
tensor(0.0049)
tensor(0.0078)
tensor(0.0088)
tensor(0.0078)
tensor(0.0122)
Averaging them gets me: 0.0083
which is very close to the value printed by the test_step().

The logic behind this solution is that I had specified in the

```
self.log('test_acc', self.test_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
```

on_epoch = True, and I used a TorchMetric class, the average is computed by PL, automatically using the metric.compute() function.

I'll try to post my full notebook shortly. You can check there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method `test_epoch_end` inside your lightning module, whose input arguments consist of a `all_outputs`. This will be an array of all the return values from each `test_step` method. Then, you can calculate customized metrics on these values all at once.

For example:

```py
def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    targets, logits, loss = self(
        batch, batch_idx, "test")
    return targets, logits

def test_epoch_end(self, all_outputs):
    # all_outputs is a list of [targets, logits] tuples from each test.
    for target, logit in all_outputs:
        # do something
    # calculate metrics based on all outputs from test.
    # log the results.
    log = {}
    log.update({'Accuracy': acc})
    self.log_dict(log)
```

Another reference may help you: [Not able to print overall results from testing](https://lightning.ai/forums/t/not-able-to-print-overall-results-from-testing/2301).